# PHP adds mysql-results double to array.

Tags: php, mysql, json

```
$query = "select * from tblRecords where record_category = '" . $cat . "' order by record_artist";
$result = $link->query($query);
```

This is the query that I use, to fetch the results, this works ok.

```
while($record = $result->fetch_array()) {
        array_push($arr_result, $record);
}
```

And this is the code I add each value to the array. But after

```
echo json_encode($arr_result);
```

This is the result set I receive:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gmggl.png

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: try var_dump($record) in your while loop

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no function like `fetch_array()` in PHP, I think you're using a predefined MySQL class which internally calls `mysql_fetch_array()`, so check the class, actually you are getting correct result but by using `MYSQL_BOTH` (**default**), you'll get an array with both associative and number indices.

Use

```
$row = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC));
```

Or

```
$row = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_NUM));
```

You must have forgotten to write a argument with `fetch_array()`.

[reference](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-array.php)

Comment: MySQLi resultsets have a method called fetch_array.

Comment: @Emil Vikström OP does not describe about that, so i was expecting as general php function with mysql. anyway thanks for knowledge

Answer (score 2):

you need to pass = > `MYSQL_ASSOC` value to `fetch_array` function

look on : http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-array.php

> Returns an array of strings that
>   corresponds to the fetched row, or
>   FALSE if there are no more rows. The
>   type of returned array depends on how
>   result_type is defined. By using
>   MYSQL_BOTH (default), you'll get an
>   array with both associative and number
>   indices. Using MYSQL_ASSOC, you only
>   get associative indices (as
>   mysql_fetch_assoc() works), using
>   MYSQL_NUM, you only get number indices
>   (as mysql_fetch_row() works).

Comment: In other words, the `fetch_array()` version creates both a regular array AND hash version of the results.

Answer (score 0):

`fetch_array` is returning both a numeric and an associative array - instead, use `fetch_array_assoc()`